# Java problem iterating through a treemap collection of classes

Tags: java, iterator, while-loop, treemap

Im trying to iterate through a Treemap of the class Tile() using:

```
Map map = new TreeMap();

Iterator itr = world.map.values().iterator();

while(itr.hasNext()){
     Tile t = ???;
     System.out.print(t.xCord+","+t.yCord+","+t.zCord);
}
```

How do I get the instance of the object Tile within the iterator? Or if theres some better way of doing this, plz let me know.

I've tried googling this, but I always end up looking at ways to iterate through pure data, like strings etc, and not Instanciations of class'...

Comment: I assume you want some space between values. e.g. try println instead of print.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings aren't pure data in Java, they are objects, so is the same:

```
Map map = new TreeMap();

Iterator itr = world.map.values().iterator();

while(itr.hasNext()){
    Tile t = (Tile)itr.next();
    System.out.print(t.xCord+","+t.yCord+","+t.zCord);
}
```

Or better:

```
Map<Key, Tile> map = new TreeMap<Key, Tile>();

Iterator<Tile> itr = world.map.values().iterator();

while(itr.hasNext()){
    Tile t = itr.next();
    System.out.print(t.xCord+","+t.yCord+","+t.zCord);
}
```

or even better:

```
Map<Key, Tile> map = new TreeMap<Key, Tile>();

for(Tile t : map.values){
    System.out.print(t.xCord+","+t.yCord+","+t.zCord);
}
```

p.s `Key` is the class of the key objects you're using

Comment: Note that `TreeMap` has two type parameters, key and value.

Comment: I took the liberty of adding a `Key` ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
Tile t = (Tile) itr.next();
```

But note that using Iterators and especially raw collections is a very outdated way of writing Java. Much better would be using typed collections and the enhanced for loop:

```
Map<String, Tile> map = new TreeMap<String, Tile>();

for(Tile t : map.values()){
     System.out.print(t.xCord+","+t.yCord+","+t.zCord);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`itr.next()` gives the instance of the next element, as specified in the [javadocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next%28%29). Note that since your Map is of raw type, you will need a cast: `Tile t = (Tile)itr.next();` but it is NOT type safe.

Even better solution is using generics as @Simone suggested

Comment: Tried that at first, didn't help. I was missing a casting. So:
Tile t = (Tile)itr.next();
Was the correct answer... But thx anyway...

Answer (score 0):

In an iterator you use

```
while(itr.hasNext()){
     Tile t = itr.next(); ...
```

However, you'd also have to cast the tile unless you gave the type with generics:

```
Map<Whatever,Tile> map = new TreeMap<Whatever,Tile>();
Iterator<Tile> itr = world.map.values().iterator();
```

Otherwise the iterator values will have to be cast - i.e. you'd have to correct your example (and the lines above) to

```
while(itr.hasNext()){
         Tile t = (Tile)itr.next(); ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Within the loop, use `itr.next()` to retrieve the next `Tile` object from the `Iterator`. Currently this will return an `Object`, since you are using a raw-typed `TreeMap`. Instead use `TreeMap<Key, Tile>`, so that the values iterator will be an `Iterator<Tile>`.

Answer (score 0):

`Tile t = (Tile) itr.next()`

This will give you the next instance of the class as well as move the iterator to the next instance.